# Is it possible to use 6GB of memory in my MacBook Pro 3,1?

Tags: macbook-pro

The specifications of my MacBook Pro say the maximum memory supported is 4GB using two 2GB DDR2 667MHz each.

However, some say that this model can support up to 6GB of memory, putting a 4GB Memory DDR3 1066MHz in one of the slot and 2GB (or 4GB, 6GB directing in this case memory).

The bus is 800MHz MacBook Pro. How should I install memory in the two memory slots to get the highest memory capacity and performance in my MacBook Pro?

Comment: Did the 6GB work in your Macbook Pro 3,1 ?

Answer (score 3):

I trust [OWC](http://macsales.com/) the most. [They say](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/5300DDR2S6GP/) that your model machine will handle 6GB of RAM. As far as which slot for each chip, that shouldn't matter. If you run into an issue, you can always swap them.